# How can I force Arduino libraries to compile code in sub-folders?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, compilation, platformio

I'm writing a BLE library for Arduino (and potentially other platforms) that needs slightly different versions of the code based on the underlying hardware.

What I'd like to do is put the platform specific code in a sub-folder called "Variants" and then use #IFDEFS in the main header file to point to the file it needs, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the compiler to "find" any code in a subfolder.  I'm using Platformio on Atom as my IDE, but I suspect this is an Arduino, not an IDE issue.

/BleStar.h

```
// Header file BleStar.h - the main Arduino code does a #include "BleStar.h" which works fine
#ifndef BleStar_h
#define BleStar_h

if defined(BLE_DEVICE_ADAFRUIT_NRF52)
   #include "Bluefruit.h"                 // The Adafruit Bluefruit library for NRF52 chipsets
   #include "Variants/AdafruitNRF52.h"    // The NRF52 specific code that I wrote
#elif define(BLE_DEVICE_ADAFRUIT_NRF51)
   #include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h"  // The Adafruit Bluefruit library for NRF51 chipsets
   #include "Adafruit_BLE.h"
   #include "Variants/AdafruitNRF51.h"    // The NRF51 specific code that I wrote
#endif

class BleStar {
public:
   ...
   // Declarations here for the hardware specific code that shows up in "Variants/AdafruitNRF51.h" etc.
   int write(uint8_t u);
   uint8_t read();
   boolean available();
   ...
private:
};
```

/Variants/AdafruitNRF52.h

```
#ifndef AdafruitNRF52_h
#define AdafruitNRF52_h

#include "BleStar.h"
// nothing in here - declarations are in BleStar.h as part of the class declaration, and AFAIK you can't split a class declaration across multiple headers

#endif
```

/Variants/AdafruitNRF52.cpp

```
#ifndef AdafruitNRF52_cpp
#define AdafruitNRF52_cpp

#include "BleStar.h"      // shouldn't hurt to repeat it
#include "AdafruitNRF52.h"

int BleStar::write(uint8_t u) {
   //nrf52 specific code
}

uint8_t BleStar::read() {
   // more nrf52 specific code
}
// etc.


#endif
```

What doesn't work:

- The above.  Using a #include AdafruitNRF52.h in BleStar.h when AdafruitNRF52.h is in a subdirectory.  I get an undefined reference to `BleStar::write(uint8_t)' error, so the compiler can't "see" the .cpp file
- using "#include AdafruitNRF52.cpp" at the bottom of BleStar.h (i.e. after all the declarations) and commenting out AdafruitNRF52.h completely.  I get a large number of compile errors like "multiple definitions of ...." despite Adafruit.cpp having header guards (and yes i know you are not supposed to include .cpp files, but i'm trying stuff)

What does work:

- Putting AdafruitNRF52.cpp in the main library directory surrounded by IF defined (BLE_DEVICE_ADAFRUIT_NRF52) /// #endifs.  It works, but then the main directory will get very crowded when I add more hardware types
- Putting separate classes in subfolders that have .h and .cpp files.  They compile fine.  I don't want to make a sub-class for this if I can avoid it, however.

Anyone know how to force compilation of code in library sub-folders?  I'm getting pretty stuck

Comment: https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/library-specification/

Comment: btw. it is only then an Arduino library if it works with Arduino IDE. the Plaformio 'arduino' is not Arduino compatible